# Origin of "Shomer Yisrael"

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, song-poetry, provenance, tachanun

What is the origin of the prayer [*Shomer Yisrael*](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C)?  Who wrote it, when and where did it first appear?

> שׁוֹמֵר יִשְׂרָאֵל! שְׁמֹר שְׁאֵרִית יִשְׂרָאֵל, וְאַל יֹאבַד יִשְׂרָאֵל, הָאוֹמְרִים: שְׁמַע יִשְׂרָאֵל.‏
>
> שׁוֹמֵר גּוֹי אֶחָד! שְׁמֹר שְׁאֵרִית עַם אֶחָד, וְאַל יֹאבַד גּוֹי אֶחָד, הַמְיַחֲדִים שִׁמְךָ: יְיָ אֱלֹהֵינוּ יְיָ אֶחָד.‏
>
> שׁוֹמֵר גּוֹי קָדוֹשׁ! שְׁמֹר שְׁאֵרִית עַם קָדוֹשׁ, וְאַל יֹאבַד גּוֹי קָדוֹשׁ, הַמְּשַׁלְּשִׁים בְּשָׁלוֹשׁ קְדוּשׁוֹת לְקָדוֹשׁ.‏

Comment: If anyone here is wise in the ways of Unicode [bidirectional text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_text) formatting:  It would be good if you could please fix the blockquote in the question.  The periods are supposed to go at the end of each verse, not at the beginning.

Comment: @unforgettableidSupportsMonica The embedded Hebrew keyboard has a `&rlm;` key which seems to fix it.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C#:~:text=%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%95%D7%98%20%D7%97%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A2.) says the authorship is unknown.

Comment: Ctrl left shift switches to right-left